# ConfigurationManager.GetSection() function

Tags: c#, configuration

Can someone elaborate how this function works? Does it load every time from disk or it caches it somewhere in memory etc?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> .NET caches this and invalidates when the web.config changes

Also when in doubt open the decompiled sources and look at the code, it not only will give you the answer but you will learn a lot..

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it means application is continuously keeping a check on web.config that whenever it is updated it loads again, right?

Answer (score 1):

When the Application runs the whole configuration is loaded into memory and whenever you try to access, your required section is retrieved from memory

Answer (score 0):

Configuration is in memory, any external change in the disk config file would have to be reloaded (standalone apps)

```
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(sectionName); [1]
```

[1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.refreshsection.aspx